# Unable to initialize main class Ejemplo1

Tags: java, import

It is a program assigned by a teacher who only said to implement the code and gives me the title error, in some IDEs it tells me that the second import does not exist.

I have searched for the error everywhere but I can't find the solution.

```
import java.util.Vector;
    import java.util.awt.*;
    
    public class Ejemplo1 {
        public static void main(String[] arg) throws InterruptedExcecption
        {
        
            System.out.println("Comienza main()...");
            Circulo c = new Circulo(2.0, 2.0, 4.0);
            System.out.println("Radio = " + c.r + " unidades.");
            System.out.println("Centro = (" + c.x + "," + c.y + ") unidades.");
            Circulo c1 = new Circulo(1.0, 1.0, 2.0);
            Circulo c2 = new Circulo(0.0, 0.0, 3.0);
            c = c1.elMayor(c2);
            System.out.println("El mayor radio es " + c.r + ".");
            c = new Circulo(); // c.r = 0.0;
            c = Circulo.elMayor(c1, c2);
            System.out.println("El mayor radio es " + c.r + ".");
    
            VentanaCerrable ventana =
                new VentanaCerrable("Ventana abierta al mundo...");
            ArrayList v = new ArrayList();
    
            CirculoGrafico cg1 = new CirculoGrafico(200, 200, 100, Color.red);
            CirculoGrafico cg2 = new CirculoGrafico(300, 200, 100, Color.blue);
            RectanguloGrafico rg = new
                RectanguloGrafico(50, 50, 450, 350, Color.green);
    
                v.add(cg1);
                v.add(cg2);
                v.add(rg);
    
                PanelDibujo mipanel = new PanelDibujo(v);
                ventana.add(mipanel);
                ventana.setSize(500, 400);
                System.out.println("Termina main()...");
    
        }// fin de main()
    }// fin de class Ejemplo1
```

Comment: Can't say I've ever seen a package of `java.util.awt` - what are you expecting to be there? Have you tried just removing the import?

Comment: You are not using `Vector` anywhere (which is, by the way, an old class you should not be using), so remove the `import java.util.Vector;` statement. Also, there is no package `java.util.awt`. You probably meant `import java.util.*;`

Answer (score 1):

There is no `java.util.awt` package. You are probably trying to import `java.awt.*`